# Intellij IDEA 12. Resource updating

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aspectj

I have a web application, i'm using javascript, java, spring, hibernate and tomcat as container.
When i'm changing js file, i just need to update it in resources. In IDEA 11 it was fast action (just one second). But IDEA 12 makes recompile of aspect j files (they are not changed), and it wastes my time.

I did not see this behavior in 11 version of IDEA. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be worth checking out the [IntelliJ issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) or JetBrains' [community forums](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please file an issue in a [tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/).

As a workaround please try to switch off external build in Settings | Compiler.